# What happens when an object is created in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, api, django-models, django-admin

I am new to Django. When we learn Python it was taught that when an object is created, the init function is initialized and all the variables that are passed are saved using self keyword. For eg:

```
class Movie:
    def __init__(self,name,caption,budget):
        self.name =  name
        self.caption = caption
        self.budget = budget

obj1 = Movie('Taken',"Fight movie",250)
obj2 = Movie('Wanted','Comedy movie',300)
print(obj1.name)
print(obj2.name)
```

Here, in the above example when I clicked the run, two objects are initialized and saved. Hence when I print both the movies names are printed.

**Now when I read the documentation in Django, it says that when we create an object of a model in Django admin, it calls the save function to save the instance**. Until now I was in the assumption that, the dunder init will be called just like in plain Python.

The Django model looks like this:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name=models.Charfield()
    dept=models.Charfield()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Also, here I don't see any init function explicitly defined. But when I ctrl + click on the Model, I can see a number of functions defined and there is init as well as save function defined. Now I want to know which function is called when we save any object from django admin. Also, if we create an object from the post api call rather than the django admin, the same function is called??

Also I dont see anywhere **str** function is called from, But it works in django-admin that name is used to represent the Employee object.Hope I have explained well.

Comment: Are you familiar with the OOP concept of inheritance?

Comment: That's a lot of questions, but to answer one of them [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/231de683d86374c2b74da2185efc6ddfb5eb3341/django/db/models/base.py#L676) is the save being called by admin (Model.save)

Comment: @jfaccioni Yes I am familiar, but I dont which function is called..is it init or save when saving from django-admin?

Comment: Why do you care about which function is called? Do you want to trigger something when an instance is saved?

Comment: Because I was asked in an interview and I couldnt answer that @ÇağatayBarın

Answer (score 1):

1. When you create instance of a model, you use the init function.
2. When you want to save the data into the database you use the save
   function.
3. The "str" function is being called by the admin site.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So that means when I create an object inside django admin, first it called init fucntion and then save function right??

Comment: I can't find the actual source code, but I am pretty sure that the answer is yes.